# Git pull request with two features on it

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am trying to determine as reviewer what to do whit a pull request that has another feature extended from it. Please see image:

[image]

How should we handle the pull request feature/newsCard that is coming from the purple branch, as it is extended with a new feature on top? Probably the developer just unintentionally created a new branch from the old one.

A: Should I consider informing that the second feature/reviewsProduct would first be finished and then merged into the feature/newsCard and then handle the pull request from the feature/newsCard I.e. `git merge newsCard reviewsProduct`.

B: Or what happens if feature/reviewsProduct is accepted to master, will that also bring the both features into master?

Any advice? the goal is just to make a safe pull into the master.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to just merge the branch `feature/newsCard` into master. This will only merge the two commits on the branch `feature/newsCard` into master but not the ones on the branch `features/reviewsProduct`. Afterwards you can wait for `features/reviewsProduct` to be finished and just merge it to master in the same way without any problems.

A bit more difficult (but maybe cleaner) way would be to rebase the commits of `feature/reviewsProduct` onto master like this:

```
git rebase --onto master feature/newsCard feature/reviewsProduct
```

this will cause the `feature/reviewsProduct` branch to start from the current commit on master (like it probably was intended to be). But this will create new commits, and maybe result in merge conflicts.

See the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more information on rebasing. Especially this part:

[image]

Comment: Ok sounds good, let's go with that. So besically this could be a way to have a dev hav their own branch and all the earlier feature commits are included locally i their new features?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you use the rebase command, all the commits that are currently on `master` and all commits that are on `feature/reviewsProduct` but not on `feature/newsCard` will be on the new `feature/newsProduct` branch. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Rebase took the feature/newsProduct to an own branch and left the purple branch with its commits :)